# Templating markdown with python (how to?)

Tags: python, jinja2, markdown, templating

I have a pipeline that outputs route tables from Azure and would like to have this output converted/embedded to/into markdown docs. So, I'm looking for ways to template markdown.

Any ideas on where to start looking?

- jinja?
- https://github.com/mikeckennedy/markdown-subtemplate ?

Any documentation with practical examples would be great. It does not necessarily need to be in python though.

Thanks